# Generic XSLT Search and Replace template

Tags: sql, xslt

I am trying to find (before re-inventing) a "simple" XSLT template that will take ANY xml document, find ALL text elements within that XML and replace all ' with ''.  I'm doing a "SELECT ... FOR XML" from SQL and then "saving" that XML for later insertion back into SQL.  After doing the SELECT FOR XML, I would like to make all ' ''s in that text before processing it further.  That way, after being integrated into other XML (which may not need such a replacement) the text will already be "SQL Safe".

Any suggestions on how to best accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: An [Identity Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) along with one other template to match all text elements and then use `replace` (XSLT2) or `translate` or EXSLT `str:replace` to do the replacement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way in XSLT 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,'&quot;','''')"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Doing it in XSLT1 is a little more problematic as it's hard to get a literal containing a single apostrophe, so you have to resort to a variable:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:variable name="apos">'</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,'&quot;',$apos)"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```